# How can a resident Indian buy and hold physical gold/silver at BullionVault?

Tags: india, gold, silver

Is it legal for an Indian resident to transact at [BullionVault](http://www.bullionvault.com)? Are there any tax implications? While BullionVault allows deposits from international banks, it only does so in dollars, pounds or euros. Do I need to have a dollar account in my Indian bank for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question has remained unanswered, I'm adding some information I have since found by way of a partial answer.
It looks like you don't need a foreign currency account for this purpose. Banks allow wire transfer in foreign currency for specified purposes.
http://www.icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/account-deposit/Outward-Remittance/faqs.html#12